# Wiremock request matching for dynamic values

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

The sample JSON I use for stub

```
 {
  "request": {
    ...
    "bodyPatterns" : [ {
      "equalToJson" : "{ \"id\": abc123  }",
      "ignoreArrayOrder" : true,
      "ignoreExtraElements" : true
    } ]
    ...
  },
```

here the id is a dynamic value, so in this case, how can I do the request matching in wire mock

Answer (score 3):

You can use a wildcard to match any value of `id`:

```
"bodyPatterns" : [ {
      "equalToJson" : "{ \"id\": \"${json-unit.any-string}\"  }",
      "ignoreArrayOrder" : true,
      "ignoreExtraElements" : true
    } ]
```